# Can webpack be used with legacy web pages?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I think maybe I misunderstood the purpose of webpack.  If I have an existing legacy web page that needs to use a class or function out of the webpack built output file...how does it get access to it?

For example, webpack has the following file packed:

```
    //test.js
    'use strict';
    var helloWorld = function(name) {
        alert('hello ' + name);
    }
    export {helloWorld};
```

If there is a button in the existing page that needs to call helloWorld('bob') onclick - how does it get access to the function?  It looks like webpack always builds the output as an anonymous closures...BUT it does return the object.  Is it poor practice to do the following:

```
var MyLib = (function(){
//...webpack logic...
return __webpack_require__(0);
})([{
// ...modules...
}]);
```

Later in the button onclick I can now call MyLib.helloWorld('bob') and it all appears to work just fine.  But since webpack doesn't generate a var there I'm sure I'm doing something bad.  What's the right way?

Comment: use `elm.addEventListenter("click", helloWorld)` from inside the module. if you have an attrib-based event (`<div onclick=...>`), you need a global variable to reach from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

By default, webpack builds for a web environment with the assumption that it's handling all of your application logic, so there is no access to the functionality in the webpack runtime from other scripts.

It looks like you want to use the [output.library](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-library) config -- this tells webpack to build your js as a library that the page can use (also see `output.libraryTarget`). In the entry point for your build, you would define the object or function that the build will expose to the page.

Comment: I'm still new at stackoverflow so I can't make it an answer yet...but yep!  That's exactly what I want...I glossed over that config option and didn't realize it was what I needed.  Thanks!